# Elementor Form: How do I pass a metadata (like RemoteIP) using webhook?

Tags: metadata, elementor

I'm using Elementor Form Pro for a "work with us" form.
I know I can send some metadata, as RemoteIP, date and time, using "Action After Submit" Email.

How can I use the same metadata using Webhook? I know the values have to be sent by JSON, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this answer is still helpfull for you. But you can reach the meta data in a webhook by using the following structure for your array:

```
array["meta"]["remote_ip"]["value"]
```

As for the fields in the form you would use:

```
array["fields"]["email"]["value"]
```

Comment: No problem! Could you accept my answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this answer is still helpful for you but you can send it via PHP using the elementor action hook: 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record'

All you have to add in the functions.php of your site is the following: & update the variables
.

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record',  'send_data_using_webhook' , 10, 2 );
    
function send_data_using_webhook( $record )
{
        $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );

        $data = array();
        
        foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
           
           $data[ $id ] = $field['value'];
        }

        // get the meta details
        $raw_meta = $record->get('meta');
        $meta = [];
        foreach ( $raw_meta as $meta_id => $meta_value ) {
            $meta[ $meta_id ] = $meta_value['value'];
        }

        $data['date'] =  $meta['date'];
        $data['time'] =  $meta['time'];
        $data['remote_ip'] =  $meta['remote_ip'];
        $data['page_url'] =  $meta['page_url'];

        $curl = curl_init("YOUR-WEBHOOK-URL-HERE");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_exec($curl);

}
```